# Best way to check if two elements of an array of array are in diagonal

Tags: java

I have indexes of two elements of an array of array (not of primitive objects) : 
first element = tab[x0][y0] 
second element = tab[x1][y1]

And i want to check if both of these elements are in diagonal like :

```
_________________
|   | * |   |   |
-----------------
|   |   |   |   |
-----------------
|   |   |   | * |
-----------------
|   |   |   |   |
-----------------
```

Here both of these points are in diagonal, so we should return true.
But what is the best way to check it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Treat the array like a Cartesian coordinate space, and calculate the [slope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope) (rise over run) of the line joining the two elements (points):

```
int rise = y1 - y0;
int run = x1 - x0;
```

If `rise` divided by `run` is 1 or -1, then the two elements form a diagonal. 1 or -1 determines the direction of the diagonal. Rather than dividing, you can just check if they have the same sign and magnitude:

```
if (Math.abs(rise) == Math.abs(run)) {
    if (Integer.signum(rise) == Integer.signum(run)) {
        // diagonal
    } else {
        // diagonal that is another direction
    }
} else {
    // not diagonal
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Two points are diagonal if the difference between the x coordinates and the y coordinates is the same.

```
x0 - x1 == y0 - y1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the coordinates. Being on a diagonal means that the differences in the `x` coordinate and in the `y` coordinate are the same. Thus:

```
boolean is_diagonal = (x1 - x0) == (y1 - y0);
```

Answer (score 2):

diagonal if

```
int x = x0 - x1 = 2
int y = y0 - y1 = 2

boolean diagonal = x == y;
```

any other combination of index will to give you an equation which means they are not diagonal. also probably you will have to use Math.abs()